# Trouble with armed bear common lisp--calling user defined classes from repl?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, abcl

I'm very new to lisp and pretty new to java as well. I was working on a trivial game in java and I thought that it would be interesting to interact with the game as I was coding it through the REPL. I have been following Practical Common Lisp and I have knowledge of basic function structure. I started using armed bear common lisp--an implementation that runs on the java virtual machine--and was able to code some basic functions for creating guis, such as:

```
(defconstant +jframe+ "javax.swing.JFrame")

(defun make-frame (length width &key visible)
  "Create a +jframe+"
  (let ((frame (jnew (jconstructor +jframe+))))
    (jcall (jmethod +jframe+ "setSize" "int" "int")
       frame length width)
    (if visible (frame-is-visible t frame))
    frame))
```

However I can not figure out how to access user defined classes from lisp. The implementation as a whole seems pretty poorly documented, and I'm finding difficulty getting started using java specific things from within lisp.  For example, I have a compiled character class called "Character". But when I call (jclass "Character") I get a "class not found" error. Is it possible to make abcl aware of my classes from within lisp?

Comment: A recent ABCL manual:  https://code.google.com/p/abcl-dynamic-install/downloads/detail?name=abcl-manual-20120205a.pdf  
It might be best to ask ABCL specific questions and suggest improvements on the ABCL mailing list. See http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/

Comment: Please clarify: which classes do you have in mind - Java classes from jars or Lisp CLOS classes defined with `defclass`?

Comment: All classes in Java have package prefixes. So you should provide something like `(jclass "my.package.Character")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an instance of a Java class that you've written yourself and that is packaged in a jar file, use add-to-classpath:

```
(add-to-classpath '("Character.jar"))
```

Then, `(jnew "org.example.Character")` should give you an instance of your `Character` class (assuming it's in the `org.example` namespace).